# Update dataframe with vales from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am tying to insert missing values in the primary dataframe with the values from a secondary and smaller dataframe. The secondary dataframe is based on "mean" values from the primary.

Python code below.

I managed to make both indexes the same but I cannot understand how to make the primary dataframe (df).
There have been several attempts but none get close the the result I am looking for.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv ('df.csv')
df2 = df.set_index(['StoreID','Product'])
#print ( list(df2.index.values) )
#print( df2.info() )
#print( df2.columns )
#print(df2)
#df2.to_csv(f"pdf.csv",
#        header=True,
#        index=True
#    )
#print("+++++++++++++++++++")
    
table = pandas.pivot_table(df, index=["StoreID"],values=["Percent"], aggfunc = 'mean')
table['Product'] = 'Computer Bundle'
table['StoreID'] = table.index
table2 = table.set_index(['StoreID','Product'])
#print ( list(table2.index.values) )
#print( table2.info() )
#print( table2.columns )
#print(table2)
#table2.to_csv(f"table.csv",
#        header=True,
#        index=True
#    )
#print("+++++++++++++++++++")

df.loc[df['Product'] == 'Computer Bundle', 'Percent'] = df.loc[df['Product'] == 'Computer Bundle', 'Percent']
print( df )

df.loc[df.Product.isin(table.StoreID), ['Percent']] = table['Percent']
print( df )

df.loc[df.StoreID.isin(table.StoreID), ['Percent']] = "12345678"
print( df )

print( df2.update(table2) )
```

Input file `df.csv`:

```
StoreID,Product,Cost,Percent,Discount
11,Book,15.18,0.08,1.21
11,Cable,0.65,0.08,0.05
11,Computer,3.56,0.08,0.28
11,Computer Bundle,25,,
11,Disk,1.19,0.08,0.1
11,Firewall,4.39,0.08,0.35
11,USB Key,1,0.08,0.08
11,Watch,0.59,0.08,0.05
22,Cable,0.11,0.12,0.01
22,Computer Bundle,3,,
22,Disk,0.01,0.12,0.01
22,Firewall,1.97,0.12,0.24
22,USB Key,0.01,0.12,0.01
22,Watch,0.61,0.12,0.07
33,Computer Bundle,0.5,,
33,Disk,0.4,0.05,0.02
33,Switch,0.16,0.05,0.01
```

The expected output would be the whole dataframe back with a few updated lines.

```
11,Computer Bundle,25,0.08,2
22,Computer Bundle,3,0.12,0.36
33,Computer Bundle,0.5,0.05,0.03
```

The missing data is the mean of the percent of each product in the store and then the discount cost. I had not got as far as putting in the discount cost code.

Answer (score 0):

To insert missing values in the primary dataframe with the values from a secondary and smaller dataframe, you can use the update() method in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["StoreID"], values=["Percent"], aggfunc='mean')
table['Product'] = 'Computer Bundle'
table['StoreID'] = table.index
table2 = table.set_index(['StoreID', 'Product'])

df.update(table2)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your original data, use `assign`:

```
(df.assign(Percent=df.Percent.ffill()).
   assign(Discount=lambda x:(x.Percent*x.Cost).round(2)))

    StoreID          Product   Cost  Percent  Discount
0        11             Book  15.18     0.08      1.21
1        11            Cable   0.65     0.08      0.05
2        11         Computer   3.56     0.08      0.28
3        11  Computer Bundle  25.00     0.08      2.00
4        11             Disk   1.19     0.08      0.10
5        11         Firewall   4.39     0.08      0.35
6        11          USB Key   1.00     0.08      0.08
7        11            Watch   0.59     0.08      0.05
8        22            Cable   0.11     0.12      0.01
9        22  Computer Bundle   3.00     0.12      0.36
10       22             Disk   0.01     0.12      0.00
11       22         Firewall   1.97     0.12      0.24
12       22          USB Key   0.01     0.12      0.00
13       22            Watch   0.61     0.12      0.07
14       33  Computer Bundle   0.50     0.12      0.06
15       33             Disk   0.40     0.05      0.02
16       33           Switch   0.16     0.05      0.01
```

If you do not care about changing the data in place:

```
df['Percent'] = df.Percent.ffill()
df['Discount'] = (df['Percent'] * df['Cost']).round(2)
df

    StoreID          Product   Cost  Percent  Discount
0        11             Book  15.18     0.08      1.21
1        11            Cable   0.65     0.08      0.05
2        11         Computer   3.56     0.08      0.28
3        11  Computer Bundle  25.00     0.08      2.00
4        11             Disk   1.19     0.08      0.10
5        11         Firewall   4.39     0.08      0.35
6        11          USB Key   1.00     0.08      0.08
7        11            Watch   0.59     0.08      0.05
8        22            Cable   0.11     0.12      0.01
9        22  Computer Bundle   3.00     0.12      0.36
10       22             Disk   0.01     0.12      0.00
11       22         Firewall   1.97     0.12      0.24
12       22          USB Key   0.01     0.12      0.00
13       22            Watch   0.61     0.12      0.07
14       33  Computer Bundle   0.50     0.12      0.06
15       33             Disk   0.40     0.05      0.02
16       33           Switch   0.16     0.05      0.01
```